# Windows GUI control option for selection of one or none

Tags: windows, winforms, user-interface

Say, if I have a GUI control where a user is allowed to select **none**, *or* **only one** of the multiple choice options. What do I use?

Check-boxes:

[image]

Or radio boxes?

[image]

Comment: Four radio buttons: None, Option 1, Option 2, Option 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Radio buttons cannot be unselected once a selection is made, unless a separate UI element is provided for that purpose.  Such an additional element would be non-standard, and thus apt to confuse some users.

A dropdown list where the first option is (None) or simply left blank is a fairly common approach that seems to meet your needs.

Radio buttons with a (None) option is just as feasible, but in practice I have not seen that.  Radio buttons also tend to take up more UI real estate than an equivalent select box.

I have seen checkboxes with additional logic to ensure that only one option is selected, but that is a non-standard UI behavior and again prone to confuse some users.

**UPDATE**

From Wikipedia's article on the Checkbox UI element, and why it is bad for the act of checking one checkbox to uncheck others:

> Setting or clearing a checkbox changes the checkbox's state with no other side-effects. Violating this guideline by associating additional actions with the change of state frequently confuses users, because they are used to configuring data in entry controls such as text boxes, radio buttons, and checkboxes and then invoking an action control such as a push button to initiate the action to process the data.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checkbox#Not_actionable

Comment: Indeed, I'd very strongly recommend against making checkboxes automatically uncheck eachother.

Comment: Thank you, guys. The issue with drop-down boxes is that they require at least two clicks to make a selection vs. one for a group of checkboxes, plus checkboxes are more readable in my opinion (as a user.) It's not much, but may make a difference for a repeated use. On the sidenote, what's wrong with using checkboxes for my purpose?

Comment: @ahmd0: Checkboxes that automatically uncheck themselves are non-standard UI behavior.  If you want to avoid the extra click of a select box, the cleanest solution would be a radio button group with an option that indicates (in what ever language suits your domain) "none".

Comment: @EricJ. Yes, it would work as such: if a user clicks on a checked box, then it becomes unchecked. If they click on an unchecked box, then it becomes checked and also previously checked box becomes unchecked. So, is it "bad" if I implement it this way? Again, in my personal opinion dropdown boxes look messy...

Comment: Yes it is "bad" if implemented that way. Updated my answer with a reason.

Answer (score 2):

Use radio buttons and provide some kind of “None of the above” option — that’s their job description.

(Though a dropdown list could work equally well.)